# Database pessimistic locking for concurrent reads using Doctrine and Azure SQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, azure-sql-database

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO**

I have a cloud application with multiple worker nodes that can each process n export requests. Export requests are placed into tables in our database. Each export request should only ever be run once. If a worker node is currently running less than n export requests, it checks every 0.1 - 1 seconds to see if there's a export request it can start processing.

The export requests that are waiting to be run are organised into a priority queue on the database side using a stored procedure. The below function (`queuePop()`) is the function that calls the database. It gets the top result from the priority queue, marks the export request as being used (it's consider being used when the status is no longer set to 'NEW') and then returns the export request to be processed elsewhere.

```
public function queuePop() {

    $entity_manager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    // Get every new export request
    try {

        $statment = $entity_manager->getConnection()->prepare( 'EXEC root.findAllNewExportRequests' );
        $statment->execute();
        $results = $statment->fetchAll();

        if ( count( $results ) > 0 ) {

            $queue_item = array (
                    'export_request_id' => $results[0]['request_id']
            );
        } else {

            $entity_manager->getConnection()->commit();
            return NULL;
        }

        // Return the export request if it exists
        $export_request = $entity_manager->find( 'Application\Model\ExportRequest', $queue_item['export_request_id'], \Doctrine\DBAL\LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_READ );

        if ( !$export_request ) {

            // Export request not found
            throw new Exception( 'Export request not found.' );
        }

        // Update the export request
        $export_request->setStatus( 'QUEUED' );

        // Update the export request in the database
        $entity_manager->persist( $export_request );
        $entity_manager->flush();

        $entity_manager->getConnection()->commit();
        return $queue_item;
    } catch ( \Exception $ex ) {

        $entity_manager->getConnection()->rollback();
        exit();
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The queuePop function works great and it ensures that a single worker node will never run an export request more than once, but when there's 2 or more nodes there's a chance that more than one worker node will pick up the request (it happens often enough given the number of requests it gets). I tried implementing pessimistic locking as seen here (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#pessimistic-locking) but it isn't working. The docs aren't very good and I can't find any examples of pessimistic locking being used properly.

I need for when one worker node is reading/updating an export request, that the other nodes can't (they have to wait).

**WHAT I'M USING**

- nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generix x86_64)
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 (fpm-fcgi)
- Zend Engine v2.5.0 with Zend OPcache v7.0.3
- Doctrine 2
- Azure SQL

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Pessimistic Write 
(Doctrine\DBAL\LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE), locks the underlying database rows for concurrent Read and Write Operations.
while PESSIMISTIC_READ only prevents the row from being updated but not from being read

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I didn't know which did which from the docs. I just attempted this and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a stored procedure for this to accomplish. Add a long enough `char` column called `hash` or so to your model and request queue table, compute a random unique ID from within your worker process prior to processing next request (PHP built-in function `uniqid()` is a good choice for that) and issue following SQL:

```sql
UPDATE export_request SET status = "queued", hash = :uniqueHash
WHERE status = "waiting"
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

(with parameter `uniqueHash` set to the unique ID you computed before, assuming `id` can be used to determine priority).

Next, retrieve the very entity you just marked as "queued" by means of the `uniqueHash` you passed to the hash column as a "marker".

The trick is that the UPDATE query is completely atomic and you do not risk any double processing due to race conditions. You even do not need a surrounding transaction for both statements (the UPDATE query will run in a transaction on auto-commit mode and your DBMS will make sure that no row will ever be queued twice because the `status = "waiting"` condition renders invalid at the same time as the hash field is set to your unique ID).